# Custom color for scale_size_continuous()

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the plot below, how do I show all `cty >= 30` values in color green and `cty < 30` values in red? Thanks!

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mpg)
p <- ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = mpg, aes(displ, manufacturer, size = cty), alpha = 0.2) +
    scale_size_continuous(breaks = c(30, 20, 10)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "red", "red"))  # does not work
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there are any `cty` values greater than 30 in the dataset, but since it is only an example, let's make the cutoff 15:

```r
ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = mpg, aes(displ, manufacturer, size = cty, 
                               color = cty <= 15), alpha = 0.2) +
    scale_size_continuous(breaks = c(30, 20, 10)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "red"))
```

[image]

If you want the legends merged, you would need a continuous color scale that emulated a discrete one, so something like:

```r
ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = mpg, aes(displ, manufacturer, size = cty, 
                               color = cty), alpha = 0.2) +
    scale_size_continuous(breaks = c(30, 20, 10)) +
    scale_color_gradientn(colors = c("red", 'red', "green", 'green'),
                          values = c(0, 0.5, 0.50001, 1),
                          breaks = c(30, 20, 10),
                         guide = guide_legend())
```

[image]

Comment: I like your 2nd plot. `mpg[mpg$cty >= 30, ]` gives me 2 values, they merge into one big green circle at top left (`manufac = volks, displ = 1.9`).